# Java OpenCV UnsatisfiedLinkError, Ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, ubuntu

I'm attempting to run the Java version of OpenCV on a hosted Ubuntu server. I have an existing application built using Eclipse from my own windows environment and i want to move it over to my server to run it there. However i am having several issues with it.

The problem is that when i try to run it i receive the following error:

[image]

Now there are existing question with varying answer to this problem already on SO, the problem being the `UnsatisfiedLinkError`, but i have tried to follow them to no avail.

I have eclipse pointing the native library location to where opencv is located on the server itself as so;

[image]

But i still have the same problem. I am compiling this project as a `Runnable Jar File` if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

The paths must match (between Windows and Linux) and you must have the right native file for each system included (and tested for).

Currently in your Eclipse environment you are pointing to a Windows implementation of OpenCV - how will Linux know where to look?

I would make sure Eclipse includes all libraries when creating a runnable jar file (it is a checkable option), and make sure that your .dll and .so files all go into the same location regardless of system (so make sure the `opencv dll` is in `c:\var\lib\opencv and libopencv_java249` is in `/var/lib/opencv` on the linux box)

In your program, since versions may not be the same, when loading the library in - do it this way too:

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
```

That way it will use whatever version is current on your system.